# Check if one of two elements are clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am checking if one button is clicked like this

```
$j('#Button1').click( function () {
```

and then performing a function but now I want to perform the same function when either Button1 or Button2 is clicked.

What is the jQuery syntax for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do this:

```
$j('#Button1, #Button2').click( function () {
```

Comment: or give `#Button1` and `#Button2` a class to select against, `<button id="Button1" class="myButtons" />` then `$j('.myButtons').click(...`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a wild card selector:

```
$('input[id^=Button]').click( function () {
```

Matches Button1, Button2, Button99, etc.